# Magento 2.3 - Modify Qty and also the variation using observer

Tags: magento2.3

ON add to cart option on product detail page . i am listening the event called `checkout_cart_product_add_before` and i created a custom observer for this.

It is getting called properly but i want to change the qty and variation which is getting passed from the request paramets.

```
$observer->getEvent()->getInfo();
```

if i print this i am getting the data properly.But i need to update the values which are in this object, based on some conditions.

Comment: when you want to change qty and variation after cart or before cart?

Comment: checkout_cart_product_add_before - before the product is added to cart. i achieved it using plugin instead